# Is there an R function to subset and remove earliest date associated with an ID?

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset where information has been collected for each ID multiple times. I would like to subset and remove the earliest date. For example:

| ID | Timestamp | Sex | Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AC1 | 2015-08-25 |  |  |
| AC1 | 2016-10-05 |  |  |
| AC1 | 2016-12-04 |  |  |

To this:

| ID | Timestamp | Sex | Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AC1 | 2016-10-05 |  |  |
| AC1 | 2016-12-04 |  |  |

Any ideas to do this on R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `dplyr` to remove the earliest date for each group. I'm providing some data here.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), time = structure(c(1325485800, 
1325487600, 1325489400, 1325491200, 1325493000, 1325494800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df.updated <- df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
  dplyr::slice(-which.min(time))
```

Be sure to provide data when asking a question to give a good [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You can do this through `dput(head(df))` to provide some of your data (as usually it only takes a little data to solve an issue).

Comment: Thank you! This worked really well! How might I change the code if I decided I wanted to remove all times but the two most recent?

Comment: df.updated<-df %>%
    arrange(ID,timestamp) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    slice(2) %>%
    ungroup()

Answer (score 1):

...and another slightly less elegant variation is the following, which uses another `dplyr` verb: `arrange`. You could do something like

```
library(dplyr)

df_new<-df %>%
    arrange(ID,timestamp) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    slice(-1) %>%
    ungroup()
```

The `slice (-1)` indicates to remove the first row by group, and since it was already arranged, you will have what you need!